# Drush not working on PHP 5.4.23

Tags: drush

My Drush was installed on /usr/local/lib/php/drush; I have now removed it from there, and installed it on /usr/share/drush.

I run the following commands.

```
chmod u+x /usr/share/drush/drush
ln -s /usr/share/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush
```

When I type `which drush`, it shows /usr/bin/drush, but when I run `drush status` or `drush version`, or any drush command, it doesn't show any result or error.

I was previously seeing errors related to Ioncube and Zend Guard Loader, but those have now been resolved, while Drush is still not working.

From `php -v`, I get the following output.

> PHP 5.4.23 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2014 23:00:41) Copyright (c) 1997-2013
>   The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend
>   Technologies
>       with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
>       with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies

My drush version is drush-7.x-5.9.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I took out the error messages you've resolved in case they distract from the real issue, hope you don't mind...do you see any errors in the php cli error log?

Comment: Thanks @Clive can you please tell me where can I find that php cli error log

Comment: Off the top of my head try /var/log/httpd/error_log. I'm not sure if cPanel changes that from the default on cent os

Comment: @Clive It depends on how you have CP installed.  The installs I have seen separate out per host you have defined.

Comment: cant find error_log under this location /var/log/httpd/

Comment: @MPD I thought cli errors might go to the 'standard' location since they don't necessarily get invoked under a jailed account...looks like that's not true. Fahad, I'd recommend getting your sysadmin's help with this, it's kind of possible to debug from here since we'd need to run commands on the server to find out what's wrong

Comment: The error was due to old .drush folder on root. After removing that it when I type the drush command it says that automatic download of console_table failed http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Table

After downloading the Console_Table the drush starts working. Since all accounts had the old php.ini file so it was giving the same ioncube and zend error when I was trying to run the drush from with in any user account. On removing the old php.ini files it is working fine. Sorry for very bad english